# How to feed weights into igraph community detection [Python/C/R]

Tags: python, c, r, graph, igraph

When using `commuinity_leading_eigenvector` of [igraph](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_leading_eigenvector), assuming a graph g has already been created, how do I pass the list of weights of graph g to `community_leading_eigenvector`?

> community_leading_eigenvector(clusters=None, weights=None,
>   arpack_options=None)

Comment: Supply it in the `weights` argument?

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to retrieve the weights from the graph. It looks like it should be something like weights=g.es[“weight”], but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: oh really? I saw the default argument being "none" so I though they would not be used...

Comment: do the weights need to be integers? I'm asking because that was the assumption per Newman's paper.

Comment: The weights are not included automatically in the Python interface. They can be any arbitrary real numbers, not only integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either pass the name of the attribute containing the weights to the `weights` parameter, or retrieve all the weights into a list using `g.es["weight"]` and then pass that to the `weights` parameter. So, either of these would suffice, assuming that your weights are in the `weight` edge attribute:

1. `g.community_leading_eigenvector(weights="weight")`
2. `g.community_leading_eigenvector(weights=g.es["weight"])`

Comment: Hi Tamas, according to Gabor they should be automatically included, so there is no need to pass them to the funciton. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, the weights are not included automatically in the Python interface so you need to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. They are included automatically in R, it seems that they are not in Python.